# Subtract from parent rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-calculation

I'm trying to subtract the value of parent header rows (which are the sum of their respective child rows) but it just keeps on adding while displaying the minus symbol. How do I subtract?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk3wN/)**

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="parent-A">
        <td>
             <h5>A</h5>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>A1</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>A2</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>A3</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="A" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent-B">
        <td>
             <h5>B</h5>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>B1</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>B2</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>B3</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="B" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total" data-par="A,B">
        <td colspan="2">
             <h4>Total A - B</h4>

        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent-C">
        <td>
             <h5>C</h5>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>C1</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>C2</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>C3</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="C" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent-D">
        <td>
             <h5>D</h5>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>D1</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>D2</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <h6>D3</h6>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-parent="D" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total" data-par="C,D">
        <td colspan="2">
             <h4>Total C - D</h4>

        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('[class*="parent-"] input').attr('readonly', true);
    var total_par = $('tr.total');
    $('input[type=text]').on('blur', function () {
        var totals = [0, 0, 0],
            parent_name = $(this).data('parent'),
            find_parent_row = $('tr.parent-' + parent_name);
        find_parent_row.nextUntil('[class*="parent-"]').find('input').each(function () {
            totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] += +this.value;
        });
        find_parent_row.find('input').each(function (i) {
            this.value = totals[i];
        });
        total_par.each(function () {
            totals = [0, 0, 0];
            var par = $(this).data('par').split(',');
            $('[data-parent="' + par[0] + '"]').add('[data-parent="' + par[1] + '"]').each(function () {
                totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] -= this.value; //subtract doesn't seem to be working!
            });
            $(this).find('input').val(function (i) {
                return totals[i];
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QAjaL/)</kbd>

**html**

```
<tr class="total" data-par="A,B"> <!-- for A-B -->

<tr class="total" data-par="C,D"> <!-- for C-D -->
```

**js**

```
total_par.each(function () {
    totals = [0, 0, 0];
    var par = $(this).data('par').split(','); // par[0] = A and par[1] = B
    $('[data-parent="' + par[0] + '"]').each(function () { //for A
        totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] += +this.value; // add all values
    });
    $('[data-parent="' + par[1] + '"]').each(function () {//for B
        totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] += -1 * +this.value;// subtract all values --> number is multiplied with -1 to make it negative and than added
    });
    $(this).find('input').val(function (i) {
        return totals[i]; //assign values to current input element inside class total
    });
});
```

---

or

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QAjaL/1)</kbd>

```
total_par.each(function () {
    totals = [0, 0, 0];
    var par = $(this).data('par').split(',');
    $('[data-parent="' + par[0] + '"]').each(function () {
        totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] += +this.value;
    });
    $('[data-parent="' + par[1] + '"]').each(function () {
        totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] -= +this.value;// subtract all values
    });
    $(this).find('input').val(function (i) {
        return totals[i];
    });
});
```

---

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/QAjaL/2)</kbd>

```
find_parent_row.nextUntil('[class*="parent-"]').find('input[data-parent="' + parent_name + '"]').each(function () {
    totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] += +this.value;
});
```

added `.find('input[data-parent="' + parent_name + '"]')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But what if I have more than two `data-par`? Like if I want to subtract A, B and C? or A, B, C and D? Is this possible dynamically (without hard-coding A and B and so on)?

Comment: When I enter the values for second and third column, the value of the first column also changes. Please check.